# BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT) when signing with ECDSA

Tags: c++, ios, crypto++, ecdsa

I am trying to use Crypto++ on iOS. I downloaded a prebuilt version of the library from [Marek Kotewicz's GitHub](https://github.com/debris/cryptopp-ios).

I am struggling hard to run [this sample code](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) from the Crypto++ wiki.

```
ECDSA<ECP, CryptoPP::SHA256>::PrivateKey privateKey;
ECDSA<ECP, CryptoPP::SHA256>::PublicKey publicKey;

AutoSeededRandomPool prng, rrng;

privateKey.Initialize(prng, CryptoPP::ASN1::secp256k1());    
privateKey.MakePublicKey(publicKey);

string signature;       
string message = "Do or do not. There is no try.";

StringSource s(message, true,
             new SignerFilter(rrng,
                              ECDSA<ECP, CryptoPP::SHA256>::Signer(privateKey),
                              new StringSink(signature)));
```

Its crashing with the following. Its showing up in Xcode output window:

```
BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
```

This is the code snippet from memory.h of c++ file where it is pointing the BAD_ACCESS

```
 _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY ~auto_ptr() throw() {delete __ptr_;}
```

I am getting BAD_ACCESS(code=1 , address=0x0) error
pointing to this line of code of library

```
 ->  0x1065dfa8d <+85>:  movq   -0x58(%rbp), %rdi
```

[image: This is the debugger output]

Comment: Can you introduce a check if the  `__ptr_`  is not `NULL` before calling `delete` I feel `~` is freeing the memory allocated to this `__ptr_`

Comment: where to check this condition ,I have written only this much code, rest of the code is present in crptopp library?

Comment: I think the problem maybe with `signature` string  which isn't initialized that you are passing. Is signature an input parameter or output parameter

Comment: signature is an output parameter

Comment: @yanivx in C++ it's explicitly safe to call `delete` on a null pointer. A check wouldn't help; the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @NikBougalis Thanks that was a learning for me

Comment: Sandeep, how about giving more details so that people know exactly how to reproduce your problem?  Where did you download the library from?  Where did the example code come from?  How are you compiling it and running it?  What is this "log" and are there any other messages in the log?  These details should have been in the original question, but it's not too late to edit it.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I added some more details.

Comment: @Sandeep - how did you make out with this issue?

Comment: @jww I couldn't solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Its crashing with the following. Its showing up in Xcode output window:
>
> ```
> BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
> ```

The code looks OK to me.

---

> I am trying to use Crypto++ on iOS. I downloaded a prebuilt version of the library from Marek Kotewicz's GitHub.

I'm just taking a stab in the dark. It presumes the code you showed above is *really* all you are doing in, say, a test `ViewController`.

The precompiled library appears to be using GNU's Standard C++ library. I would switch to LLVM's Standard C++ library by building Crypto++ with `-stdlib=c++` (and not GNU's `-stdlib=stdc++`). Apple switched to it years ago, and Xcode uses it by default.

You can find a GitHub with the fat library using LLVM Standard C++ at [noloader/cryptopp-5.6.2-ios](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-5.6.2-ios).

Or, you can build the fat library yourself. For that, see [iOS (Command Line)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/IOS_%28Command_Line%29) on the Crypto++ wiki. The prebuilt library at [cryptopp-5.6.2-ios](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-5.6.2-ios) uses those instructions.

---

> ```
> AutoSeededRandomPool prng, rrng;
> ```

You only need one of these.

---

> ```
> StringSource s(message, true,
>                new SignerFilter(rrng,
>                    ECDSA<ECP, CryptoPP::SHA256>::Signer(privateKey),
>                        new StringSink(signature)));
> ```

Over the years, I've come to wonder about the temporary signer created for the pipeline. I've changed the Crypto++ wiki to stop using them. Use this code instead:

```
ECDSA<ECP, CryptoPP::SHA256>::PrivateKey privateKey;
...
ECDSA<ECP, CryptoPP::SHA256>::Signer signer(privateKey);
...

StringSource s(message, true,
               new SignerFilter(prng, signer,
                   new StringSink(signature)));
```

Comment: I used the library you pointed to and now its giving bad access error again and logs as mentioned in my edited question

Comment: @SandeepAggarwal - did you make the change to construct a unique `ECDSA<ECP, CryptoPP::SHA256>::Signer`, rather than a temporary one? The code still shows the temporary one.